# Unable to run JS file in custom WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of converting a Bootstrap template into a WordPress theme, and I've got all of my stylesheets and scripts referenced in functions.php, and a few initialization codes in footer.php, but there's one particular file that's not executing correctly: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/js/creative.js.

Script:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    })

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Fit Text Plugin for Main Header
    $("h1").fitText(
        1.2, {
            minFontSize: '35px',
            maxFontSize: '65px'
        }
    );

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Initialize WOW.js Scrolling Animations
    new WOW().init();

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

I've set this particular file to use jQuery and to be called before the `</body>` tag via functions.php, but none of the scripts inside are executing and Chrome is returning this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function`

I've tried replacing the `$` alias with `jQuery`, but it had no effect. I've also confirmed this is getting called after the jQuery library.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try loading this script at the bottom of the page ?I can see in the original theme it is loaded at the last. Try loading after bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to link bootstrap.min.js or link it correctly

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have the following in functions.php:
`wp_enqueue_script ('bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');`